# How to achieve dark transparent background on persistent bottom sheet swipe up?

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

i´ve implemented a persisten bottom sheet in my android app by using

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="85dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">
      ...
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

in an `ConstraintLayout`. It works very well. I can swipe up to open it in `STATE_EXPANDED` and i can swipe it down to the `STATE_COLLAPSED`.

Now my problem:
When I expand the bottom sheet it overlaps the main content, which looks very confusing. To solve this, I would like to dim the background to highlight the expanded persistent bottom sheet like in an modal bottom sheet (see the picture...).
[image: Modal BottomSheet with dark background]

Is there a way to dim the background when my persisten bottom sheet turns into state `STATE_EXPANDED`? Ideally with an smooth animation, in which the background gets darker, the more I swipe up. But I just want to have a transparent dark background when the persistent bottom sheet is in `STATE_EXPANDED`. In the `STATE_COLLAPSED`, the background should be normal and not dimmed.

I didn´t found a solution on the internet. Could anyone help me? Or provide and information or experience?

Comment: If you use a BottomSheetDialogFragment background dimming will be handled for you.

Comment: Yes, I know, but is there a possibility to show this BottomSheetDialogFragment as a persistent bottom sheet without the shadow in mode_collapsed?

Comment: there is no way to make it with default persistent bottom sheet, just make ur own (it's easy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for your answers and your help. It seems that there is no offical way to achieve the explained behaviour.
After some coding, I have an working solution. I post this approach here on myself, to help someone who is also looking for an solution for this functionality.

I placed a view as an background layer behiind the `BottomSheet`:

```
        <View
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheetBackgroundLayer"
        android:background="#99000000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Then i change the alpha value of this view in an `bottomSheetCallback` like this:

```
        override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, @BottomSheetBehavior.State newState: Int) {}

        override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
            bottomSheetBackgroundView.setAlpha(slideOffset)
        }
```